# How to sync video stream and other comment information?

Tags: video-streaming

I need to synchronize a video stream and some related information stream,basically some marker position in the video. So I can draw the markers in the video frame and play out together.

How could I do with that?

Comment: Do you want to "overlay" the information on the existing stream?

Comment: @SamerTufail yes,I need to sync the information frame by frame. Because in my application there are few moving items in the video. I want to tap the item at the client side. and send the item index back to server.

Comment: is gstreamer an option for you?

Comment: @SamerTufail yes. I just need to meet the requirement. No matter what tool I am using.

Comment: I would suggest you install gstreamer first, read some FAQs on gstreamer first. Gstreamer has a plugin called gstvideooverlay which will do exactly what you want. Although familiarize yourself with gstreamer first.